# Nested linq - where x == enumerable

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0, subsonic3

I'm new to Linq and SQL terminology - can someone tell me why this isn't working (syntax is not right - I can't compare u.UserID int with an Enumerable)

```
var projectUsers = from u in SimpleRepository.All<User>()
                   where u.UserID == (from i in SimpleRepository.All<ProjectUser>()
                                      where i.ProjectID == p.ProjectID
                                      select i.UserID)
                   select u;
```

In "english", that would we "select every user where their id matches any of (userID from ProjectUser collection where projectID == x) and give me a collection of users".

I'm also using subsonic3 with a SimpleRepository if that makes a difference (or allows me to use something else to make this easier).

Comment: Please define "isn't working".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var projectUsers = from u in SimpleRepository.All<User>()
               where (from i in SimpleRepository.All<ProjectUser>()
                                  where i.ProjectID == p.ProjectID
                                  select i.UserID).Contains(u.UserID)
               select u;
```

or

```
var projectUsers = from u in SimpleRepository.All<User>()
               join u2 in SimpleRepository.All<ProjectUser>() on u.UserID equals u2.UserId
               where u2.ProjectID == p.ProjectID
               select u;
```

Comment: how do we test for linq expressions like the one above since we don't have reference to SimpleRepository & other objects?

Comment: @SoftwareGeek: i did not test them actually :-S but if i would do that - then i will just create list of integers and make something close to the tested one. don't you agree that doesn't matter whether we use LINQ with objects or integers?

Comment: Thanks zerkms, I learnt a bit from googling the terminology in the second example.

Comment: @George R: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx - this can be useful too